# Use a TabletPC as an input device for another computer

Tags: kvm-switch, graphics-tablet, windows-tabletpc

I have a 12" TabletPC that I want to use as the input device for another computer. I know of apps like Multiplicity and Synergy that will allow me to use a mouse on another computer over the network, but they don't carry pressure information as far as I know, and absolute positioning doesn't work.

Are there any similar programs that might be suitable for diong TabletPC input over network?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your tablet's pen "device" will be an USB device. If so, you should be able to use some network USB redirection tools.

- If you're using recent Windows versions you might be able to use [RemoteFX](https://web.archive.org/web/20160201151237/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2010/06/10/introducing-microsoft-remotefx-usb-redirection-part-1.aspx) (new version of RDP) to forward your tablet's pen device to the other computer.
- Otherwise, you could try some [commercial product](https://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-for-remote-desktop.html).
- Sure there are some other tools I don't know of.

I used neither of these, because I was searching for a tool to redirect from a local Mac to s remote Windows host (and sadly found none).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out when my tablet is fixed -- the SSD drive I bought for it failed on me :(